# ff_replay substructure in ff_effect empty

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, hid

I am developing a force feedback driver (linux) for a yet unsupported gamepad.

Whenever a application in userspace requests a ff-effect (e.g rumbling), a function in my driver is called:

```
static int foo_ff_play(struct input_dev *dev, void *data, struct ff_effect *effect)
```

this is set by the following code inside my init function:

```
input_set_capability(dev, EV_FF, FF_RUMBLE);
input_ff_create_memless(dev, NULL, foo_ff_play);
```

I'm accessing the `ff_effect` struct (which is passed to my `foo_ff_play` function) like this:

```
static int foo_ff_play(struct input_dev *dev, void *data, struct ff_effect *effect)
{
    u16 length;
    length = effect->replay.length;
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "length: %i", length);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, that the reported length (in `ff_effect->replay`) is always zero.

That's confusing, since i am running fftest on my device, and fftest definitely sets the length attribute: https://github.com/flosse/linuxconsole/blob/master/utils/fftest.c (line 308)

```
/* a strong rumbling effect */
effects[4].type = FF_RUMBLE;
effects[4].id = -1;
effects[4].u.rumble.strong_magnitude = 0x8000;
effects[4].u.rumble.weak_magnitude = 0;
effects[4].replay.length = 5000;
effects[4].replay.delay = 1000;
```

Does this have something to do with the "memlessness"? Why does the data in `ff_replay` seem to be zero if it isn't?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is the replay struct empty?

Taking a look at https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/drivers/input/ff-memless.c#L406 we find:

```
static void ml_play_effects(struct ml_device *ml)
{
    struct ff_effect effect;
    DECLARE_BITMAP(handled_bm, FF_MEMLESS_EFFECTS);

    memset(handled_bm, 0, sizeof(handled_bm));

    while (ml_get_combo_effect(ml, handled_bm, &effect))
        ml->play_effect(ml->dev, ml->private, &effect);

    ml_schedule_timer(ml);
}
```

`ml_get_combo_effect` sets the effect by calling `ml_combine_effects`., but `ml_combine_effects` simply does not copy `replay.length` to the `ff_effect` struct which is passed to our `foo_play_effect` (at least not if the effect-type is FF_RUMBLE): https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/drivers/input/ff-memless.c#L286

That's why we cannot read out the ff_replay-data in our `foo_play_effect` function.

### Okay, replay is empty - how can we determine how long we have to play the effect (e.g. FF_RUMBLE) then?

Looks like the replay structure is something we do not even need to carry about. Yes, **fftest** sets the length and then uploads the effect to the driver, but if we take a look at `ml_ff_upload` (https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/drivers/input/ff-memless.c#L481), we can see the following:

```
if (test_bit(FF_EFFECT_STARTED, &state->flags)) {
    __clear_bit(FF_EFFECT_PLAYING, &state->flags);
    state->play_at = jiffies +
             msecs_to_jiffies(state->effect->replay.delay);
    state->stop_at = state->play_at +
             msecs_to_jiffies(state->effect->replay.length);
    state->adj_at = state->play_at;
    ml_schedule_timer(ml);
}
```

That means that the duration is already handled by the **input**-subsystem. It starts the effect and also stops it as needed.

Furthermore we can see at https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L279 that

```
/*
 * All duration values are expressed in ms. Values above 32767 ms (0x7fff)
 * should not be used and have unspecified results.
 */
```

That means that we have to make our effect play at least 32767ms. Everything else (stopping the effect before) is up to the scheduler - which is not our part :D